# Access tab controller views?

Tags: ios, xcode

I started an app with a single view controller. I've since added a tab controller view and created 4 views that are setup as tabs, and that all seems ok.

The only viewcontroller.swift file I have is the original one. I'm not sure how to access the view controllers for each of the individual tabs.

Should I just use the one viewcontroller.swift for all my code and link the controls in each tab back to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the other view controllers, create classes of your `UIViewController`, like so. I'd recommend you put each class in a separate Swift file in your project, but it's not necessary.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}

class FourthViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}
```

Then assign them in the Identity Inspector by clicking each Storyboard `UIViewController`:

[image]

Comment: Oh! So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I make tabViewController just like this. Make my own viewcontrollers. First, init my own viewcontrollers. Then, push them into tabViewController.viewControllers

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad();
        let first = YourFirstViewController();
        let second = YourSecondViewController();
        let thrid = YourThirdViewController();

        self.viewControllers = [first, second, third];
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way, u can program without storyboard